# Two parameter template acting differently from one parameter in call

Tags: c++

For an assignment (this is a fairly small part I've been stuck on, I'm not asking for anyone to do the homework), we were supplied with the following code and its call in the main file:

```
template <class number_type>
class Point {
public:
  Point(const number_type& x_, const number_type& y_) : x(x_),y(y_) {}
  // REPRESENTATION
  number_type x;
  number_type y;
};

template <class number_type, class label_type>
class QuadTree {
public:
    QuadTree(const number_type& number_, const label_type& label_) : number(number_), label(label_){}

    number_type number;
    label_type label;
    };

int main() {
std::vector< std::pair<Point<int>,char> > simple_points;

QuadTree<int,char> simple;
}
```

However, using a very similar style to the supplied coding produces a "no matching function" error in my terminal:

I'm confused as to why it doesnt work in this case, as well as what I can do to fix it.

As a note, we are not allowed to use c++11, structs, and a few other tools. Also, we are not permitted to change anything in the "main" function, so QuadTree simple; MUST stay as-is

```
main.cpp: In function ‘void simple_test()’:
main.cpp:110:22: error: no matching function for call to ‘QuadTree<int, char>::QuadTree()’
   QuadTree<int,char> simple;
                      ^
main.cpp:110:22: note: candidates are:
In file included from main.cpp:14:0:
quad_tree.h:56:5: note: QuadTree<number_type, label_type>::QuadTree(const number_type&, const label_type&) [with     number_type = int; label_type = char]
     QuadTree(const number_type& number_, const label_type& label_) : number(number_), label(label_){}
     ^
quad_tree.h:56:5: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
quad_tree.h:54:7: note: QuadTree<int, char>::QuadTree(const QuadTree<int, char>&)
 class QuadTree {
       ^
quad_tree.h:54:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

Comment: Please include an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a full error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
QuadTree<int,char> simple;
```

is attempting to call the default constructor. However, since you provide a constructor, the default constructor is implicitly deleted. The constructor you provided is:

```
QuadTree(const number_type& number_, const label_type& label_)
```

So you'd have to do:

```
QuadTree<int, char> simple(42, 'C');
```

Comment: @NickL Because you never tried to do something like `Point<int> p;`

Comment: Right before you commented back I did try that, to the same result. Even with the restriction of not being allowed to alter what was in main, I was able to figure out that I just needed to remove my constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Your `QuadTree` constructor takes 2 parameters, but you probably (based on your error message) have a definition like

```
QuadTree<int,char> simple;
```

which declares an object with no parameters passed to the constructor. You need to do something like

```
QuadTree<int, char> simple(2, 'a'); // need to specify the parameters
```

Note that because you defined a constructor, the compiler does not generate a default one for you anymore.